# detecting onClick with Awesomium in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, awesomium

I'm building a menu system for an XNA framework game with Awesomium. The menus are visible and mouseState events are getting injected to my webViews successfully (have some CSS rollover stuff working). But I cant seem to execute methods in my C# code when the onClick event is triggered in my menu buttons.

**C#**

```
        private void OnViewProcessCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JSObject menu = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("menu");

        if (menu == null)
            return;

        using (menu)
            menu.BindAsync("onButtonClick", myJSMethodHandler);
    }

    private void myJSMethodHandler(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MethodName == "onButtonClick")
        {
            WebCore.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

**JS/HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Main UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
    {
        object.onclick = menu.onButtonClick;
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="d1">
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b1" onclick="menu.onButtonClick();">Agents</h1></p>
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b2" onclick="">Research</h1></p>
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b3" onclick="">Infrastructure</h1></p>
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b4" onclick="">Financial</h1></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed unnecessary JS function and called bound function directly from element.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Main UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="d1">
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b1" onclick="menu.onButtonClick();">Agents</h1></p>
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b2" onclick="">Research</h1></p>
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b3" onclick="">Infrastructure</h1></p>
        <p><h1 class="button1" id="b4" onclick="">Financial</h1></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also realised the OnViewProcessCreated function is never getting called, not sure why. Created a JSObject in the main Awesomium function and it ran fine.

```
    public AwesomiumMenu(string Source, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        // CSS styling
        const string SCROLLBAR_CSS = "::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: hidden; }";
        WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig()
        {
            CustomCSS = SCROLLBAR_CSS
        });

        webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        webView.ReduceMemoryUsage();
        webView.Source = Source.ToUri();
        webView.IsTransparent = true;

        while (webView.IsLoading)
            WebCore.Update();

        Rectangle = rectangle;
        JSObject menu = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("menu");
        menu.BindAsync("onButtonClick", myJSMethodHandler);
    }
```